# Join tables to query for a random row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one contains data created by an individual user and that data is assigned a unique primary key. My second table contains ratings of the aforementioned data and contains the user that created the rating, the actual rating, and the ID of the data being rated.

> Table one, [data][user][data_id]
>
> Table two, [rating][user][data_id]

I want a query that gives me a random row from table one based on the pretense that table two contains no ratings of random row being returned.

I think this will require a join, but I keep getting stuck. Is this possible with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM tableOne 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableTwo WHERE tableTwo.data_id = tableOne.data_id) = 0
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Just got it up and running. I had an additional requirement that I forgot to add, "do not return a row if the user specified was the one to create it.", that wasn't on you though, I just forgot to add that.

Comment: I added the line, "AND tableOne.user != ?"

Comment: Otherwise, your answer was the first provided and after thirty minutes of testing it seems to be a great working solution! Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. I was just curios if the query worked.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It may be a little faster than doing the `COUNT` method, depending on your tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableOne t1
LEFT JOIN tableTwo t2
  ON t2.user= t1.user
 AND t2.data_id = t1.data_id
WHERE t2.user IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

This assumes that your `user` column is not nullable.